# sorting functions don't sort the array correctly

Tags: php, sorting

I want to sort whole bunch of keys in an array. The key-value pairs are of a large number and a name. It sorts arrays incorrectly on small numbers and it gets even worse when numbers get too big to be stored as integers. If the integers are too big they are stored as strings in an array. And those strings don't sort at all staying in the same place.

All i want to do is to sort the Key-value pairs from largest to smallest. 
I have no idea how to do that since the sorting functions fail completely.
I'll appreciate any help I can get.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

$encodedNames = $_GET['names']; //names array from a html input encoded with  JSON.stringify(nameArray);

$names=json_decode($encodedNames); //decode the names

$namesLegacy = (array) NULL;  //array that will store key-value pairs (number=>name)

//for each name gets a large number and assigns it as a key
foreach($names as $name){
    $name = trim($name);
    array_push($namesLegacy, array(getFameNumber($name)=>$name)) ; 
}

echo var_dump($namesLegacy) . "<br />";//dumps the array before it is sorted
krsort($namesLegacy);
echo var_dump($namesLegacy) . "<br />";//dumps the array after its sorted

//simply prints each name in a list format
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($namesLegacy); $i++) {
   $keys =  array_values($namesLegacy[$i]);
    echo $i+1 .". ".$keys[0] . "<br/>" ;
}


//gets the large number that will become a key and returns it , as a string ? 
function getFameNumber($name)
{
    $resultTagId = "resultStats"; 
    $name = str_replace(" ", "+", trim($name));

    $url='url that will return the large number';
    /*can be tested with google url 
    $url='http://www.google.com/search?q='.$name.'&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t';*/   
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $data = curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);

    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    @$dom->loadHTML( $data );
    $resultsTag =  $dom->getElementById($resultTagId)->nodeValue;

    $results =  preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",$resultsTag);
    return $results;
}
?>
```

**Update:**
I have run more examples to test if it will sort all non string values correctly and it turns out that it doesnt. (where previously it has worked now it fails)
I have an array

```
array(3) { [0]=> array(1) { [1800000000]=> string(6) "Robert" } [1]=> array(1) { [591000000]=> string(6) "albert" } [2]=> array(1) { [1100000000]=> string(4) "Anna" } }
```

and when i run krsort() on it it returns

```
array(3) { [2]=> array(1) { [1100000000]=> string(4) "Anna" } [1]=> array(1) { [591000000]=> string(6) "albert" } [0]=> array(1) { [1800000000]=> string(6) "Robert" } }
```

which is not the correct result correct result is 
1800000000,
1100000000,
591000000

I tried to converting those string into floats but it mostly made them come out as negative numbers. So i tried going the other way converting small ints to strings, but the strange thing is that they were already strings. It seems that they are converted to ints when i form a key value pair inside an array.

anybody knows what is going on? am i using krsort incorrectly is the problem still because the numbers are too big?

also I will give an example of how it looks like when i have a really big number in my array

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["4430000000"]=> string(3) "son" } }
```

notice the "" marks around the number where in previous arrays its not there

**Update2:**

Ok so i know it has nothing to do with how big the integers are. 
I placed this code to test it `$results = substr($results, 0, -3);`
but i still get incorrect results

```
array(3) { [2]=> array(1) { [1550]=> string(5) "Reeta" } [1]=> array(1) { [1800000]=> string(6) "Robert" } [0]=> array(1) { [1090000]=> string(4) "Anna" } }
```

I also reversed keys and values and tried sorting with `arsort()` with same results

If anyone could explain why strings get converted to ints when they are set as keys in the arrays that would be greatly appreciated as well.

here is a [krsort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.krsort.php) manual.

Comment: It's illegal to fetch and use google search results. They will ban you shortly

Comment: @zerkms Im not fetching the actual search results im just fetching the number that represents how many results for a query search there are.

Comment: it doesn't matter. Be prepared to be banned.

Comment: my latest comment was just a notification, that sooner or later (actually sooner) you'll get your script broken. And it's a good idea to think already now what to do in that case, because you're just wasting time for implementing something that won't work.

Comment: The final results will not use Google anyways I just use that to test it. Numbers and names will be very similar (but the website is not up yet so i cannot test it with that website)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$key = getFameNumber($name);
array_push($namesLegacy, array("$key"=>$name)) ;
```

Comment: this doesnt work the small ints are still ints while too large ints are strings